# How to control the order of ggplot2::geom_pointrange elements by colour, shape and linetype

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data=data.frame("X"=c(22,5,8,17,7,22),
"XMIN"=c(17.6,4,6.4,13.6,5.6,17.6),
"XMAX"=c(26.4,6,9.6,20.4,8.4,26.4),
"VAR"=c('A','B','C','A','B','C'),
"L1"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
"L2"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))


ggplot(data) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(
    ymin = XMIN,
    ymax = XMAX,
    y = X,
    x = reorder(VAR, -X),
    colour = factor(L1),
    shape = factor(L1),
    linetype = factor(L2)))
```

I wish to add space between the lines for each variable A,B,C. Also within (A,B,C) for each variable I wish to sort the line from lowest to highest by X value.

See photo here,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5JT8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:
Updated in response to comments so that variables `L1` and `L2` control the colour, shape and linetype aesthetics.

The really tricky problem was overcoming the conflict between the order imposed by using `factor(L2)`  and that wished for as a combination of `VAR` and `X`.

The axis order will trump the linetype order where the x values are distinct.

So created a continuous variable x_loc to locate observations on the x axis which are then re-labelled with the required values from `VAR`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data=data.frame("X"=c(22,5,8,17,7,22),
                "XMIN"=c(17.6,4,6.4,13.6,5.6,17.6),
                "XMAX"=c(26.4,6,9.6,20.4,8.4,26.4),
                "VAR"=c('A','B','C','A','B','C'),
                "L1"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                "L2"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))

# reorder the data to be in the right plotting order: grouping by VAR with X in ascending order, then everything follows quite nicely.

data1 <- 
  data %>% 
  arrange(VAR, X) %>% 
  mutate(x_loc = c(0.8, 1.1) + rep(0:2, each = 2))


data1

ggplot(data1) +
  labs(x = "VAR") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = data1$VAR[1:3])+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  geom_pointrange(aes(
    ymin = XMIN,
    ymax = XMAX,
    y = X,
    x = x_loc,
    linetype = factor(L2),
    colour = factor(L1),
    shape = factor(L1)))
```

Which results in:

[image]

Note: for some reason I do not fully understand adding additional `ggplot` layers after the `geom_pointrange` function resulted in revealing the list elements of the 'ggplot' layer. Something to follow up another time.

Comment: thank you so much that is really close but it does not seem to work in my actual data I think because the color, shape, and linetype depends on L1 and L2 as shown in stead of VAR. Do you have thoughts on getting it to work with those?

Comment: OK, I thought `L1` and `L2 `were dummy variables to force the factor order. I'll take a closer look. So you want colour and shape to relate to `L1 `and linetype to `L2`? It looks as if `L1` maps to `VAR` or is that just a coincidence?

Comment: yes please, that would be wonderful. The idea is that I have different measures of VAR for each L1 and L2 combination. Thank you so much I have not been able to figure this out!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `geom_pointrange`? is it essential that you use this `geom`?

Comment: no particular reason except it is pretty straightforward. Do you know of any way to make the graph like shown in the sample image?

Comment: you are a genious!

Comment: thank you, I did try but it doesn't let me because my reputation is too new...but I will when I earn the reputation!

Comment: OK fully understand